# GO - Package name of files

Tags: go, package

I learnt that, all `.go` files in a directory must name the same package.

---

Considering below [example](https://github.com/fogleman/nes) from github,

```
fogleman/nes/
  nes/  
    apu.go  
    cartridge.go
    console.go  
    controller.go
    cpu.go  
    filter.go   
    ines.go 
    mapper.go   
    mapper1.go  
    mapper2.go  
    mapper3.go  
    mapper4.go  
    mapper7.go  
    memory.go   
    palette.go  
    ppu.go  
  ui/   
  util/
  .gitignore    
  LICENSE.md    
  README.md 
  main.go
```

---

So, All `.go` files in directory(`../fogleman/nes/nes`) have the package name `nes`(same as directory name).

Similarly, all  `.go` files in directory, `../fogleman/nes/ui` have the package name `ui`(same as directory name).

---

Considering below two files,  I have a question,

1)

`roms.go` file in directory(`../fogleman/nes/util`) has package name `main`(different from directory name)

2)

`main.go` file in directory(`../fogleman/nes`) has package `main`(different from directory name).

**Question:**

Why package name(`main`) is different from its directory name?

Comment: Directory name and package name don't need to match, they just usually do by convention.

Comment: @JimB If I need to import `roms.go` symbols in another file, then,  do I need to say `import github.com/fogleman/nes/util/main`?

Comment: You only import by path, but you can't import a main package; `main` is the program entry point.

Comment: @JimB  `main` in `package main` is just a package name. Why does it have an implication of not getting imported?

Comment: No, main is not only a package name, it's defined as the package that contains a `main` function and is setup as the program entry point. Every program needs a single `main` package, you can't import multiple.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the author of this repo intended on running roms.go as a separate program for testing. Without putting this file in package `main`, this could not be done. If you are in the root project directory:

`cd util`

`go run roms.go path/to/roms/dir`

Comment: Does GO allow multiple(more than one) `.go` files in a directory(`../fogleman/nes/util/`) or directory(`../fogleman/nes/`) with `package main`?